# PHP json_encoding is not coming properly

Tags: php

When I convert from array to json it's not working properly

php code

```
$url = 'api link'; // It's not correct link
    $ch = curl_init();      
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
          echo json_encode($response);
```

Array result

```
Array ( [0] => m_vijay [1] => l_rahul [2] => c_pujara [3] => v_kohli [4] => a_rahane [5] => r_ashwin [6] => w_saha [7] => r_jadeja [8] => j_yadav [9] => u_yadav [10] => s_ahmed )
```

My output result

```
"Array\n(\n [0] => m_vijay\n [1] => l_rahul\n [2] => c_pujara\n [3] => v_kohli\n [4] => a_rahane\n [5] => r_ashwin\n [6] => w_saha\n [7] => r_jadeja\n [8] => j_yadav\n [9] => u_yadav\n [10] => s_ahmed\n)\n"
```

I tried number of times I didn't get it. Please help me

Comment: Check your response. It sounds like it may already be encoded.

Comment: how can i convert into json format like {0:m_vijay,1:l_rahual} like

Comment: You're getting a text representation of an array (print_r) back as a result?

Comment: no. echo $response

Comment: So you mean yes.  That is a print_r of an array you can't do anything with that.  The host should send you something like a json encoded array.

Comment: There is no array involved in the posted code. `curl_exec()` returns a string. That string apparently is the output of `print_r()` when it was passed an array as argument. The value returned by `json_encode()` seems the correct one, given the input string you pass to it. You probably need to use `json_encode()` instead of `print_r()` on the server code (assuming it's under your control).

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it now.

Comment: Can you provide output of `print_r($response)` , just to be sure whats the problem.

Comment: Are you tried,  echo json_encode($response, true);

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you try to encode the encode :)
Try this :

```
print_r(json_encode((object)$response));
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: i got result like this                                                               object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["scalar"]=> string(223) "Array ( [0] => m_vijay [1] => l_rahul [2] => c_pujara [3] => v_kohli [4] => a_rahane [5] => r_ashwin [6] => w_saha [7] => r_jadeja [8] => j_yadav [9] => u_yadav [10] => s_ahmed ) " }

Comment: Then what i will do? :(

Comment: Thanks for your corporation :( :) any solution

Comment: {"scalar":"Array\n(\n [0] => m_vijay\n [1] => l_rahul\n [2] => c_pujara\n [3] => v_kohli\n [4] => a_rahane\n [5] => r_ashwin\n [6] => w_saha\n [7] => r_jadeja\n [8] => j_yadav\n [9] => u_yadav\n [10] => s_ahmed\n)\n"}

Comment: Hmm very strange because I am getting this: `{"0":"m_vijay","1":"l_rahul","2":"c_pujara","3":"v_kohli","4":"a_rahane","5":"r_ashwin","6":"w_saha","7":"r_jadeja","8":"j_yadav","9":"u_yadav","10":"s_ahmed"}`

Comment: You don't get an array, you get a String! You can't convert a String with "array(..." to json... it must a real php array.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not an array, it is a string formated by print_r, normally the requested string must be formated like json. Please var_dump() the response before you do any thing with it.